# RunTime Error even when the code is working and pass the tests in Eclipse but it is not working in OnlineJudge

Tags: java

This is my code, it works properly but when i try to submit it to OnlineJudge i receive a RunTime Error.
The code is for the 3n+1 problem, and the results seem fine. I tried submitting other codes i have found in github and those codes are Accepted but this one doesnt.

import java.util.*;

class Problema1 {

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
try {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
    int a= sc.nextInt();  
    int b= sc.nextInt();  
    System.out.println(problema(a,b));
    }
}catch(Exception e) {
    
}finally {
    System.exit(0);
}

}
public static int cycleLength(int n) {
int resultado =0;

for(int i=2; n!=1; i++) {
        if (n%2 != 0) {
            n = 3*n + 1;
            resultado = i;
        }else {
            n = n/2;
            resultado = i;
        }
    }

return resultado;
}

public static String problema(int i, int j) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = 10000;
    int mayor;
    int menor;

    ArrayList<Integer> resultados = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int resultado =0;
    
    if(i>j) {
        mayor = i;
        menor = j;
    }else {
        mayor=j;
        menor=i;
    }
    
    if(min<i && i<max && min<j && j<max) {
        for(int p=1; menor <= mayor; p++) {
            resultados.add(cycleLength(menor));
            menor ++;
        }
        for(int v=0; v <resultados.size(); v++) {
            if(resultados.get(v) > resultado) {
                resultado = resultados.get(v);
            }
        }
    }
    return (i +" "+ j + " " +  resultado);
}
```

}

Comment: Does it have a traceback? Just saying code throws "RunTimeError" doesn't narrow down things a lot.

Comment: No, it only says RunTime Error.